# promise is still pending in then block - how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch, isomorphic-javascript, isomorphic-fetch-api

I have code something like -

```
fetch(`${URL}${PATH}`)
   .then(res => {
       const d = res.json();
       console.log("data is: ", d);

       return d;
    })
```

It logs `data is:  Promise { <pending> }`.

What to do to see results and utilize in next code statement?

Other questions and answers suggests to use then block to resolve, but I'm still seeing it unresolved.

Comment: `res.json()` is asynchronous as well. See the first example here: [MDN: Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: That suggests `then`to resolve, but mine is pending even in then block.

Comment: Have you read Tylers comment? you need to handle the promise in `res.json()` **aswell**

Comment: @Prakhar `fetch` requires *two* `then`s. `fetch() -> then -> result.json() -> then -> process result`.

Comment: Okay - I'm new to this world. I got it now.

Comment: Does this works differtly with `graphql-request` - `return request(this.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, query, variables) .then(res => { console.log('data is: ', res); return res; })`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res.json()` is asynchronous. You will need to use an additional .then to get the result.

```
fetch(`${URL}${PATH}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(d => {
    console.log('data is: ', d);
    return d;
  });
```

Comment: Does this works differtly with `graphql-request` - `return request(this.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, query, variables)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('data is: ', res);

        return res;
      })`

Comment: Apparently I'm getting pending with this now?

Answer (score -1):

Well If you are getting this type of value **`Promise { <pending> }`**. Always remember to resolve it. 
So your query would resolve to

```
fetch(`${URL}${PATH}`)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(console.log)
   .catch(console.error)
```

For better understanding you can leverage the use of **async/await** feature. The above code would reduce to-

```
try{
   const res = await fetch(`${URL}${PATH}`)
   const dataAsJson = await res.json()
   console.log(data)
}
catch(ex) {
   console.error(ex)
}
```

Comment: How to resolve in debugger?